# In vb. net, How to know whether an object has specific property

Tags: vb.net, properties

I want to do translation recursively on all components in my form. So my function will start on the form. Before the recursion, it's obvious that I have to know what property containing the children that the current Object has.

e.g.

- if current Object is myForm (type: Form), it has property Controls as
  the target of recursion
- if current Object is myLiv (type: ListView),
  it has property Items as the target of recursion, which it doesn't
  have property Controls.
- etc.

The method I want to use it, I will check if the current object has property Items if not, check if it has property Tabs, and so on... Then the last fallback, check if it has property Controls.

Now the very question how could I check if the current object has specific Property?
NB without prompting any error...

Comment: You do know that there's translation support [built into](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y99d1cd3(v=VS.80).aspx] the .Net framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to do this, but that means you take a performance hit.

Alternately you can do it with the `Is` operator to check to see what kind of `Object` you have and then casting to that type.

Comment: It's one of solution. But I use more than 30 components (textbox, label, tabcontrol, listview, also 3rd party components e.g. telerik).

Using that approach will make me writing if/elseif for all components. It works but not quite smart approach.

So my approach is to determine what property that holds the children..

Comment: And you can do that with reflection...just like I said...but it is a major performance hit.

Comment: I'm not going to spell it out for you.  .NET in general is excruciatingly documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.aspx).  Here's two links for you: [Number one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx), [number two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx).